# Unhandled exception at 0x53918F0E (ucrtbased.dll)

Tags: c, function, loops, do-while

```
**#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void buildArray(); 
int main(void)
{
    int example[20];
    buildArray(example);
    getch();
}

void buildArray(int param[]) {
    int i = 0;
    do {
        printf("Please enter number :");
        scanf("%d", param[i]);
        i++;
    } while (param[i] != -1);
}**
```

hello i want to get input from user. when will user entered -1 number , i want to break this loop. But i getting some error code : ""Unhandled exception at 0x53918F0E (ucrtbased.dll) in HelloC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.""

where is my fault? 
When i was try to change function type from void to int, getting same error.

Comment: What did you discover when you used a debugger?

Comment: Please instruct your compiler to issue warnings. It will tell you that your `scanf` call is wrong. (Also: Does `param[i]` refer to the same entry when scanning and when checking whether to break the loop?)

Comment: Well , i'm using visual studio. http://i67.tinypic.com/167wj7o.png

Comment: When you compiled your program, you should have gotten messages in the Error List. Read them. Like the one that says `C4477: 'scanf': format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int'`.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues, firstly this

```
scanf("%d", param[i]);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", &param[i]); /* need to provide address */
```

Also `buildArray()` prototype should be

```
void buildArray(int *);
```

instead of

```
void buildArray();
```

Also `do..while` condition is wrong, use `param[i-1]` instead of `param[i]` in condition part of the loop.

Sample Code

```
void buildArray(int param[]) {
        int i = 0;
        do {
                printf("Please enter number :");
                scanf("%d", &param[i]);
                printf("entered : %d\n", param[i]);
                i++; /* because of this, condition part should be param[i-1] != -1 */

        }while(param[i-1] != -1); /* it should be param[i-1] */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was work. I have an question. why we changed from `void buildArray(int);` to `void buildArray(int *);`

Comment: Because from `main()` you are passing `example` which is an  _integer array_ i.e address, so `buildArray()` argument should be of `int*` type not just `int` type. Or you can declare like `void buildArray(int param[]);`